# Xcode: how to fix Thread 5: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10025c76c)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift2

when I click the btnLogin in the iPhone the xCode was displayed the error:

Thread 5: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10025c76c)

this is my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var abc: UILabel!
       
   ...

@IBAction func btnLogin(sender: UIButton) {
    
    var jsonResult = AnyObject?()
    
    let urlAsString = "lifewinner2015.dlinkddns.com/SERVER/user?function=login&username=Shing&password=123456789"
    
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)
    
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    
    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, reponse, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("error")
        }
        
        do {
            jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
            let jsonAbc: String! = jsonResult!["return"] as! String
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.abc.text = jsonAbc
            })
        } catch let err as NSError! {
            if (err != nil) {
                print("JSON Error")
            }
        }
    })
    jsonQuery.resume()
    
}
```

1. run the app on the iPhone (9.2 Version)
2. click the Login button
3. Xcode will display the error(Photo 1)

   Photo 1: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/loErxm.jpg]

**please help me to fix this error please.**

---

but I am not to add the breakpoint to the line number

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT8AY.png]

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add a breakpoint in xcode ? Check to the left of the line (around the line number)

Comment: NO!!  I do not add the breakpoint, but the xCode was displayed the error

Comment: I can not find the Photo 1 problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that's not an error ... its breakpoint .. just remove it or continue program execution by tapping the button described in the next picture.

[image]

or for remove breakpoints just drag and remove them from the breakpoint navigator

[image]

one more thing don't make force unwrap.. use if let to unwrap like

```
if let jsonAbc = jsonResult!["return"] as? String{
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.abc.text = jsonAbc
        })
}
```

one more possibility is added in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525677/thread-1-exc-breakpoint-code-exc-i386-bpt-subcode-0x0-error?rq=1) that "Take a look at the Window in Interface Builder and try to temporarily remove all reference to any IBOutlet present in the View Controller"

Answer (score 0):

have you deleted button?

if yes then you may want to check the outlet of button..

just right click on button in story board and find in property inspector if there are two or more action or outlet performed on button.

If there are two action ..one you are currently using and another which was added previously and you have removed from your.swift file you must delete the referring outlet from the button too just keep in mind..

Comment: it is one action only

Comment: try 
print(jsonResult) if your result getting any result or not

Answer (score 0):

Probably the thread checker for CoreData is enabled

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You added a breakpoint in xcode, probably without noticing. Go the file, right click on the line number where you breakpoint is, and select "delete breakpoint"