# Error while testing login through facebook and firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos

Folks!
I had a problem while I was making login through facebook sdk and firebase, I got strange error and don't know what to do,could you help, please?

**debugger output**
[image]

**code of function**

[image]
The same thread that comes in function is showing in appDelegate.
Thank's in advance

Comment: is it breakpoint I think ... remove your breakpoints and check

Comment: Don't put image of code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) please use the `edit` function and add the code as [formatted code]() to your question. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: for more info., how to continue execution, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860313/xcode-how-to-fix-thread-5-exc-breakpoint-code-1-subcode-0x10025c76c/35860406#35860406

Comment: You've put three breakpoints on line on line 22, 23, 24. Remove them(Right click on each of those breakpoints and select `Delete Breakpoint`). Clean (shift + cmd + k) and run again.